How to correct Path format for a file in Java using Path in Windows
I'm working on a Java project running on a Windows machine, and I have a configuration file located in src/main/resources. This file contains an entry for a directory path:
<entry key="myRepo">src/main/resources/myRepo</entry>

In my code, I read the path like this:
Path path = Paths.get(Application.cfg.getString("myRepo"));

Later, I pass this Path to a method in a class imported from a JAR file (I cannot modify the JAR code):
String htmlcda = CdaXSLTransformer.getInstance().transform(cda_xml, "en-GB", Application.cfg.getString("myUrl"), path);

The problem is that when path is processed, it uses backslashes () instead of forward slashes (/), which results in an error because the method expects a properly formatted URI-like path.
For example, the path is processed as:
file://src\main\resources\

This format causes an error. I cannot modify the method to accept a URI instead of a Path.
I've tried using path.toUri(), but this returns a URI, which I cannot pass to the method.
How can I ensure the Path is interpreted correctly in Windows and used in a format compatible with the method, without modifying the JAR file or the method definition?

maybe transform the URI to String using toString() (assuming the method accepts a String) - that is, Paths.get(Application.cfg.getString("myRepo")).toUri().toString()

@user85421 the method accepts only Path.

A method expecting a Path but at the same time expecting it to be a URI (or having a specific separator) is broken. If it is your method, fix it, if it isn’t, send a bug report to the author.

for me it seems like a bug in that method - a Path should only consist of the parts of the path, but not the separator, that is added when using its toString() or similar

Path shouldn't come into it. You are dealing with resources.

Path is interpreted correctly in Windows. It's not interpreted correctly inside some jar, in code not shown - so have voted to close this question.

I'm working on a Java project running on a Windows machine Just to be clear, the OS doesn't come into it either, since resources are inside a jar, the path separator of which is always a forward slash

The weird thing here is to at all refer to src/resources.

That's true too ;)

Resources are (in a Java application packaged in a JAR) not on the filesystem, but inside the JAR (or at least, somewhere opaque on the classpath), as such trying to refer to them with Path is wrong, unless your jumping through hoops to also use a ZIP filesystem to open the JAR, instead of locating it using Class/ClassLoader getResource/getResourceAsStream.

On your computer, in your own project, your configuration file (and possibly other application resources) is present in src/main/resources.  However, after your application is compiled and built, it does not know about the src directory.  That is your own private source code.  The actual application, which presumably other people will run on other computers, will not have any source code in it.
Application resources are data that is bundled with the compiled program.  Since there is no source code tree when the application is running outside of your own project, you can’t be sure of any file locations.
Moreover, most Java applications are distributed as .jar files or Java modules.  Both of those are single-file archives.  Since each is just one file, the contents of the archive obviously cannot be separate file paths themselves.
This is a common need in applications, and there is a standard, easy to way to handle it:  the getResource method of java.lang.Class.  Resources should never be accessed using the Path or File classes.  They should always be accessed as URLs only (or InputStreams).
You were right to try to pass a URI directly.  If CdaXSLTransformer does not have a method that accepts a URI, then I would look at what other transformer methods it does have.
If it has a method which accepts a URL, you can pass the resource directly:
String repo = Application.cfg.getString("myRepo");
String url = Application.cfg.getString("myUrl");

// It is a mistake to have src/main/resources in this value!
if (repo.startsWith("src/main/resources")) {
    repo = repo.substring("src/main/resources".length());
}

URL repoLocation = getClass().getResource(repo);
String htmlcda = CdaXSLTransformer.getInstance().transform(cda_xml, "en-GB",
    url, repoLocation);

If CdaXSLTransformer has a method that accepts an InputStream, you can pass the resource as an InputStream:
String repo = Application.cfg.getString("myRepo");
String url = Application.cfg.getString("myUrl");

// It is a mistake to have src/main/resources in this value!
if (repo.startsWith("src/main/resources")) {
    repo = repo.substring("src/main/resources".length());
}

String htmlcda;
try (InputStream repoSource = getClass().getResourceAsStream(repo)) {
    htmlcda = CdaXSLTransformer.getInstance().transform(cda_xml, "en-GB",
        url, repoSource);
}

If CdaXSLTransformer does not have any methods that accept a URL or an InputStream, and it absolutely requires a Path object, then you should copy your resource to a Path temporarily:
String repo = Application.cfg.getString("myRepo");
String url = Application.cfg.getString("myUrl");

// It is a mistake to have src/main/resources in this value!
if (repo.startsWith("src/main/resources")) {
    repo = repo.substring("src/main/resources".length());
}

Path repoPath = Files.createTempFile(null, null);
try (InputStream repoSource = getClass().getResourceAsStream(repo)) {
    Files.copy(repoSource, repoPath,
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

String htmlcda = CdaXSLTransformer.getInstance().transform(cda_xml, "en-GB",
    url, repoPath);

Files.delete(repoPath);

Unfortunately, if your only option is to pass a Path, then as long as CdaXSLTransformer is doing something as foolish and naive as "file://" + path, there is nothing you can do.  A Path object does not actually contain file separators, so you cannot make its string form contain different separators.
And even if you could, a URI has restrictions on which characters are allowed.   The URI for C:\Program Files is not file:/C:/Program Files, because spaces are not legal characters in URIs.  The correct URI would be file:/C:/Program%20Files, which string concatenation obviously can’t produce.  In theory, you could use Peter’s solution to return a URI-escaped form of your Path, but then the toString() method would not conform to its general-purpose contract and would not be usable for any other purpose.

Path is an interface.
Probably that method is using it wrongly.
But you could create a wrapper for Path:
public class FixPathForCdaXsltTransformation implements Path {
  private final Path original;
  public FixPathForCdaXsltTransformation(Path original) {this.original = original;}
  public String toString() {
  // call super.toString, replace \ with /
  }
  // implement all other methods, delegating to original path.
}

It will be a work around, however it will fix your issue for now.
